# Where is the desktop background stored in a Server 2008 R2 roaming profile?

Tags: windows, windows-server-2008-r2

I'm not sure why this has been so hard for me to find but where, oh where, is the desktop background stored in a roaming profile on Windows Server 2008 R2?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Do you have Application Data redirected? Try %appdata%\Microsoft\Windows\Themes\TranscodedWallpaper.jpg

Comment: Somehow I was not finding this. Sheesh.